# Export real-time data from scada wincc to google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, plc, wincc

Is there a way to connect realtime data from wincc scada to google sheets?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to do so using VB Scripts which are very similar to VBA.

Here is a link from someone who did the same from an Excel sheet: [How to write to a “Google Spreadsheet” from Excel 2003 VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9737354/how-to-write-to-a-google-spreadsheet-from-excel-2003-vba).

You can use the VB Script to create almost the same structure (without strong types) and populate the value fields with your tag values, qualities and anything else.